# Markov chain subchains yield bigger chain

Tags: markov-chains

Assuming both $X \to Y \to Z$ and $Y \to Z \to W$ are Markov chains, I want to prove that $X \to Y \to Z \to W$. I don't really know how to do that. The normal formula is:

$P(x,y,z,w) = P(x) P(y|x) P(z|x,y) P(w|x,y,z)$

Now, because $X \to Y \to Z$ is a Markov chain, I know that I can replace $P(z|x,y)$ with $P(z|y)$ and because $Y \to Z \to W$ is a Markov chain, I know that I can replace $P(w|x,y,z)$ with $P(z|x,z)$. But how can I get rid of the $x$?

Comment: This seems to be false.  Where did you find this problem?

Comment: @BrianMoehring It's an exercise for some class of mine

Comment: And you haven't left any details out?

Comment: No, just the definition of $X \to Y \to Z \to W$ but I guess that should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, this is false.

Let $X,Y,Z$ be i.i.d. and let $W=X$.